# How to exit a while loop

Tags: command-line

I am trying to exit a while loop as soon as it returns no output.

So if I am monitoring (with a while loop) the output of a command that changes, how do I exit the loop once the string I am monitoring no longer exists. (Say "purple" disappears from the output string in the example below)

```
$ while :; do clear;  "is_purple_present_monitoring_script" | grep purple  ; sleep 15; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the last command in condition-list that determines when the `while` loop exits.

```
while
  clear
  "is_purple_present_monitoring_script" | grep purple
do
  sleep 15
done
```

You could move the condition to the action-list and use `break` there (and use `true` or `:` as the condition-list) like with:

```
while
  true
do
  clear
  "is_purple_present_monitoring_script" | grep purple || break
  sleep 15
done
```

But that would be quite a contrived way to use a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks both of you. This one did the trick. Newbie to posting on this forum, seems to have a amazing group of people around here :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`break`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html) statement:

```
while :; do
    clear;
    if ! "is_purple_present_monitoring_script" | grep purple; then 
        break
    fi;
    sleep 15;
done
```